# error expected ';' before instance

Tags: c++

Quick overview of how I got to this.

1. Created the structure
2. Created the **.cpp** file
3. Used *CMake* to create *Make* file
4. Ran *Make* and received error

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum UnitType { Meter, Inch };
class Meter {
    double value;

    public:
        Meter(double value) : value(value) {}
        double convertTo(UnitType unit) {
            if (unit == Inch) {
                return value * 39.3700787;
            }   
        };  
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try 
    {   
        Meter meter(1.0);
    }
    catch (int e) {
        cout << "exception " << e << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but, I'm receiving the following error:

```
$ make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/convert-length.dir/convert-length.cpp.o
/convert/length/convert-length.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:                                    
/convert/length/convert-length.cpp:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘meter’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/convert-length.dir/convert-length.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/convert-length.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm hoping this is a silly C++ syntax error somewhere that I'm missing, but I've spent a couple hours looking for it with no success. I have little C++ experience, but this code looks syntactically correct. Does anyone see or know what is wrong?

Comment: on `convertTo` you do not need the `;` on the closing `}`. You only need a `};` for the class `{}`

Comment: The code in the `try` block can throw no exceptions (you call no library functions, you do no dynamic allocation, and your code does not throw any exceptions).  The `try` and `catch` blocks are wholly unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
enum UnitType { Meter, Inch };
```

Here you've defined `Meter` as a enumeration value.

```
class Meter {
```

...but here (at the same scope) you're trying to re-define it as the name of a class. That's legal, *but* to make use of it later, you have to use `class Meter`, instead of just `Meter`:

```
class Meter meter(1.0);
```

IMO, even though you *can* use the same name for both, it's likely to lead to confusion and problems that are much better avoided by simply renaming one or the other (or maybe both).

Comment: Or for even more name fun, `class Meter Meter(1.0);`!

Comment: @James McNellis: If you keep using language like that, you're going to have to wash your mouth out with soap -- and worse, decipher `if if .eq. then then the = else else then = endif endif` for the next few years. Oh wait, you're writing C# now -- Fortran might be more fun.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that jumped out at me reading this sample

1. The `convertTo` method does not return on all code paths
2. The `convertTo` method has an `;` after the closing `}`.
3. The identifier `Meter` is listed twice: Enumeration value and class name.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has pointed out: Meter is both an enumeration and a class name.

A little trick that allows you to keep the same name:

```
class UnitType
{
    public:
       enum UnitType { Meter, Inch };
};


int main()
{
   // Meter enum is now inside the scope of UnitType

   UnitType::UnitType  type = UnitType::Meter;
   Meter               meter(1.0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename either your enum member "Meter" or class name "Meter"

Answer (score 0):

Change "Meter" in the enum to something else because it conflicts with the class name "Meter".

Secondly, you need to add a return value for the function "convertTo" in the case that "unit != Inch".

Answer (score 0):

Change the enum type into METER and INCH because you even have the class name as Meter.

Comment: Using all upper case can cause problems with pre-processor macros which are traditionally all uppercase.